# Reset scrollTo() data

Tags: javascript, jquery, scrollto

I have some weird problem. I'm using `scrollTo()` plugin for scrolling my page. I have up and down arrows for vertical scroll and left and right for horizontal scroll. Problem is, when I click on right arrow, it scrolls to right side, then if I click on down arrow, it first goes to left section, then goes down and then it goes right again. But it should scroll only down. As you can see in my code, I reinitalize `call()` function, so I believe `scrollTo()` remembers previous position and then follows that previous path.

So my question is, how to reset `scrollTo()` data when I call that function again.

**Html**

```
<section class="main">
        <section class="section0">
            <img src="1-1.jpg">
        </section>

        <section class="section0">
            <img src="1-2.jpg">
        </section>

        <section class="section0">
            <img src="1-3.jpg">
        </section>
    </section>

    <section class="main">
        <section class="section1">
            <img src="2-1.jpg">
        </section>

        <section class="section1">
            <img src="2-2.jpg">
        </section>

        <section class="section1">
            <img src="2-3.jpg">
        </section>
    </section>
```

**Jquery**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    call(0);
});

function scrollToPosition(element) {
    if (element !== undefined) {
        $("html").scrollTo(element, 800, {
            margin: true
        });
    }
}
var counter = 0;
var call = function(counter) {

    var sections = $('.section'+counter);
    var position = 0;
    var next = $('#up');
    var prev = $('#down').hide();

    next.click(function(evt) {
        prev.show();
        scrollToPosition(sections[position += 1]);
        if (position === sections.length - 1) {
            next.hide();
        }
    });

    prev.click(function(evt) { 
        next.show();
        scrollToPosition(sections[position -= 1]);
        if (position === 0) {
            prev.hide();
        }
    });

}

$(function() {

    var sections = $('.main');
    var position = 0;
    var next = $('#right');
    var prev = $('#left').hide();

    next.click(function(evt) {
        counter++;
        call(counter);
        prev.show();
        scrollToPosition(sections[position += 1]);
        if (position === sections.length - 1) {
            next.hide();
        }
    });

    prev.click(function(evt) { 
        counter--;
        call(counter);
        next.show();
        scrollToPosition(sections[position -= 1]);
        if (position === 0) {
            prev.hide();
        }
    });

});
```

Comment: What do you mean with "I reinitalize `call()` function"? Everytime you call `next.click(...)` you add a new function to the click event. This does not remove previously added functions. So, when you click on the next button, it executes all functions that were added before.

Comment: When I said 'reinitalize' I meant to reset everything inside that function. Is there a way to remove previously added function.

Comment: You can use [`next.off('click')`](http://api.jquery.com/off/) to remove event handlers.

Comment: Thank you, your last comment helped me @Jan